# Remove existing log file and create new log file in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, logfile

I have log file which is grown to 1TB. I have no need of log file. Just want to delete the old log file and create a new one instead of old log file.

How can I achieve that ? will it cause any other problem? pleas help.

Comment: That seems like a bad idea. if it's that big, have you done a transaction log backup recently? Why not do one and then shrink the file (if you have to).

Comment: It really depends on several other things: 1) what version of SQL Server?, 2) is this your database’s only log file, or does it have more than one?  3) what is the Backup Mode setting of the database? 4) have you been doing regular database backups?

Comment: Also, how big is the database’s datafile(s)?

Comment: @larnu for this db, log file is not required

Comment: "log is not required"? Every database has a log file. It is **required**.

Comment: @rbarryyoung
1. version: 2014
2. Yes log file is for my db only
3. Full
4. No we dont

Comment: @larnu : Haha.. i agree. I meant, we have no need to backup log

Comment: If you don't need a log backup, why is your database in full backup mode? Either use Simple or backup or logs. This is why you're in the position you are in...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Brought database to offline and deleted log file manually from file system. And bring database back to online. Thats worked out.

Comment: This left my database unaccesible. I do not recommend this.

Comment: This is very dangerous, you will corrupt your data if there is something still in the logs

Answer (score 3):

Right mouse button on the database and

```
TASKS -> SHRINK -> FILES
```

Then choose the option that interests you

More :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/shrink-a-file?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: This *might* work and it might be what the OP needs, but it depends on several other things (see the comments to the question, above)

Comment: I know, that's why I put a link to the documentation @RBarryYoung

Comment: But that link won’t resolve any of the (most likely) problems that they probably have.  Which is that Shrinkfiles probably won’t shrink the log at all because the are probably in FULL mode and haven’t done the proper backups.

Comment: I gave the option to check, I am waiting for the author's comment, maybe this is it, maybe not. @RBarryYoung

Comment: Shot in the dark, fair enough.  In my experience though, they most likely have their backups mis-configured, and once that is fixed, then Shrinkfiles will work.

Comment: You can be right, I do not have that much experience with it. @RBarryYoung

Answer (score 1):

I made a backup of the database (very important just in case something fails or trying something else you brake up things!) and then I detached and reatached the database, but deleting the ldf file from the reataching window. This creates a new ldf file as expected in the original database but empty.

[image]

More details here:
https://inapp.com/delete-sql-server-database-transaction-log-file/

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
create database cmsdb on
(filename = 'd:\programfiles\microsoft sqsl server \msql12.mssqlserver\mssql\data\cmsdb.mdf')
for attach_rebuild_log
go
```